# Connect a VM with an Autonomous Database in Oracle Cloud Free Tier

Tags: oracle

I have created an Autonomous Database and a VM in Oracle Cloud Free Tier. Later on I installed the Instance Client in the VM. In order to connect the VM to the database, it is my understanding that I must create first a Service Gateway. When trying to do so, I get this error message: "The maximum limit of 0 for Service gateway per VCN has been exceeded". In Oracle Cloud Free Tier is not possible to create a Service Gateway? If not, what alternative one have in order to connect a VM with an autonomous database?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a service gateway. You can connect to your autonomous DB directly from you VM using, for example, the JDBC driver.

See this link for more information:
https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/jdbc-db-cloud.html